# How do I change pages tapping custom bottom navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to switch between 3 pages ("Home", "Search", and "My Account")  by tapping custom navigation bar I made following some tutorials. Unfortunately, the tutorial video ended after designing tab bar.
[here is a screenshot of my custom tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60x2f.png)

I have been watching different videos and trying to find out how to do it but no luck.
Would appreciate if you could help me with adding pages to this custom bottom tab bar.
Thank you in advance.

Please kindly see my code here.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class NavBarController extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavBarController({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavBarControllerState createState() => _NavBarControllerState();
}

class _NavBarControllerState extends State<NavBarController> {


int selectedIdex = 0; 

Color backgroundColor = Colors.white;

List<NavigationItem> items = [
  NavigationItem(Icon(Icons.home), Text('Search Home'), Colors.blue),
  NavigationItem(Icon(Icons.search), Text('Find Agent'), Colors.blue),
  NavigationItem(Icon(Icons.people), Text('My Account'), Colors.blue)            
];


Widget _buildItem(NavigationItem item, bool isSelected ) {
  return AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    height: double.maxFinite,
    width: isSelected ? 165 : 70,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
    decoration:  BoxDecoration(
      color: isSelected ? item.color : Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)) 
    ),
  
    child: ListView (
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget> [
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget> [
          IconTheme(
          data: IconThemeData(
            size: 24,
            color: isSelected ? backgroundColor : Colors.grey,
          ),
          child: item.icon,
        ), Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
          child: isSelected ? 
          DefaultTextStyle.merge(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: backgroundColor
            ),
          child: item.title,
        ) 
        : Container(),
        )
          ],
        )
 
      ],
    ),
  );
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 65,
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 55, horizontal: 20),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        color: backgroundColor,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
            spreadRadius: 0.5,
            blurRadius: 10,
            offset: Offset(0,5),
          )
        ]
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, //! iCons Alignment 
          children: items.map((item) {
            var itemIndex = items.indexOf(item);
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIdex = itemIndex;
                });
              },
              child: _buildItem(item, selectedIdex == itemIndex),
            );

          }).toList(),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
class NavigationItem {
  final Icon icon;
  final Text title;
  final Color color;
  
  NavigationItem(this.icon, this.title, this.color);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

bottom tap bar navigation is indeed not very well documented or implemented in Flutter. But, there are ways to do it effectively.
First, you can use Cupertino components, CupertinoTabBar, CupertinoScaffold... It's a all-in-one solution to have bottom tab bar navigation. See [here].(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html)

There is another option if you want more customisation:

Use IndexedStack with your pages:

```
Widget _buildPage(NavigationItem item) {
    if (item == "something")
        return SomePage();
    else if (item == "something else")
        return SomeOtherPage()
    else
        return SomeDefaultPage()
}

BottomNavigationBarItem _buildBottomNavigationBarItem(int index) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(
          items[index].icon
        ),
        label: item[index].text,
        );
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
              body: IndexedStack(
                children: for (var item in items) _buildPage(item),
                index: selectedIndex,
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(currentIndex: selectedIndex, onTap: (int itemIndex) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIdex = itemIndex;
                });
              }, items: List.generate(
                     items.length, (index) => _buildBottomNavigationBarItem(index)),
                 selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
                 unselectedItemColor: Colors.white)
            );
}
```

Using a Scaffold is better to have a good layout.
We just use the body property to show an IndexedStack, which takes a list of widgets (pages in our case) and only shows the one that corresponds to the selectedIndex.

Then, the bottom app bar is in bottomNavigationBar. The component is already made by Flutter, we just have to pass onTap callback, the items (icons, labels...) and there are other options to customise the color when selected...

I personally prefer the second option as it allows you to fully customise all of the elements.
Also, if you want to implement tabbed Navigation inside the tabs, you can just return Navigator() widgets inside the _buildPage() function.